# Angular 4 (click) isn't working on <i> element

Tags: angular

Hello i have quick question. Can anyone explain to me why (click) isnt working on  html element?

I've found way around this by placing whole th element in  tag and applying (click)

table.component.html

```
<th>Date of creation <i class="fa fa-sort" (click)="sort()"></i></th>
```

table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DocumentsService } from '../documents.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sort(){
    console.log("test");
  }
}
```

So I'm just curious why this is not working on  element?

Comment: Is there any chance you're applying `pointer-events: none` to the `<i>` element in css?

Comment: Is your icon from font-awesome showing up? Make sure your icon is there. alternatively, try putting text in between the <i></i> and see if your function works

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Please provide a plunkr if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing written between the `<i></i>` tags, so there is no word to click or raise the click event. Write something between tags and you will be able to call your sort method.

Comment: There is an icon